# Docusign API: Multiple signatures in same ceremony

Tags: docusignapi

I'm investigating the feasibility of my company using the DocuSign API for a specific scenario. We are generating PDFs on our side which we then wish to use embedded signatures to sign on our end. The form must be signed by two parties, who are both physically present in the same session.

It sounds like Docusign isn't friendly towards the idea of submitting custom PDFs with signatures on them, as opposed to applying signatures to uploaded template PDFs. It also sounds like it does not want to do two different signatures in the same ceremony for security / auditing reasons. Is this correct? I'm not interested in doubling my number of round trips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DocuSign can handle this scenario via one embedded signing session per signer. That way, each signer sees what is appropriate to them, the auditing is complete, etc.

You could also enable each signer to sign via their own mobile phone rather than passing around a tablet or somesuch.

Yes, there would be more than one API call to set this up. API call times to create a new signing session are quick. This is a frequent use case for DocuSign customers and developers.

Comment: Thank you! That's what I needed to know. I figured as much, but I wasn't entirely sure and wanted to make sure I wasn't missing some option in the documentation - my first day looking at this API. Much appreciated.